Decidability using oracle
I have the language:
G = {<B,w> | B is an oracle TM and B[ATM] accepts w}
I need to prove if this language is decidable relative to ATM.
How would I go on about doing that??
My idea was to build a machine that just asks the oracle of ATM if <B,w> participates in ATM, but that seems "too simple" to be correct..

What do $A_{TM}$ and $B[A_{TM}]$ mean in $G$?

ATM = {<M,w> | M is a Turing machine that accepts the word w}                            B[ATM] means B is a Turing machine that uses an oracle of ATM, ie a machine that can answer the question of whether a M,w set belongs to ATM or not. We don't know how that machine works, we just know it can give us yes or no answers in finite time

You cannot ask an oracle of $A_{TM}$ whether $B[A_{TM}]$ accepts $w$, because $B$ is not a standard Turing Machine, it has an oracle.
Just to put you on the right track: is there really a difference between $G$ and $A_{TM}$? (apart from the oracle)
Try to recall how you proved that $A_{TM}$ is undecidable.

Why can I not ask A_TM's oracle about B? Why does the fact that B uses an oracle disable my ability to ask the oracle of  A_TM?

Because the oracle knows how to solve $A_{TM}$, and the inputs for $A_{TM}$ are Turing Machines, not Turing machines with an oracle. It's just not the same "creature".

So basically I can prove it with Cantor's diagonalization, just like ATM

Yes, exactly. (Although to my knowledge this is usually not referred to as Cantor's diagonalization, but rather just "diagonalization". Cantor is reserved for pure sets, as well as the uncountability of the real numbers).

Since we already know ATM is undecidable, couldn't I reduce this language to ATM, or is it not possible because they're basically the same language

It's not clear what you mean by "reduce it to this language": you're not trying to show that this problem is harder than $A_{TM}$, that's trivial. You're trying to show that it's undecidable even with an $A_{TM}$ oracle. That's a much stronger claim.
